# Deploy de serviço windows para ec2

Tags: deploy, amazon-aws

Atualmente quando preciso fazer o deploy automatizado da minha aplicação web para o EB (Elastic Beanstalk) da Amazon utilizo a ferramenta de linha de comando abaixo:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\Deployment Tool\awsdeploy.exe

Para ela, posso passar um arquivo de configuração com informações de bucket do s3, autenticação e ambiente para deploy.
Essa ferramenta atualiza todas as máquinas que são gerenciadas pelo ELB.

Contudo, quando preciso ter este mesmo comportamento para serviços windows em máquinas ec2 não tenho essa mesma facilidade.

Atualmente a única forma que tenho em mente para trabalhar é iniciar a máquina manualmente e instalar o serviço. Se o serviço precisa de atualização tenho que entrar manualmente em cada máquina que o serviço está rodando ou fazer com que o próprio serviço saiba se auto-atualizar.

Contudo, mesmo que o serviço possa atualizar-se por si próprio, a primeira instalação tem que ser manual.

Existe algum meio que possibilite o deploy e instalação de serviços em máquinas windows no EC2 da amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há diversas maneiras de se fazer isso. Aqui vão apenas algumas sugestões. Dependendo de quão crítico seja o seu serviço (se ele pode sair do ar por alguns instantes, ou não) pode ser que uma dessas te sirva:

1. Usar CloudFormation para atualizar todo o stack. Se você nunca utilizou diretamente, há uma barreira de aprendizado mas vale a pena. O Beanstalk por exemplo é pouco mais que um template de CloudFormation com uma GUI.
2. Instalar o serviço em uma (ou todas) as máquinas da aplicação Beanstalk. [Esse artigo](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1RLX98N5ERPSA/Customizing-Windows-Elastic-Beanstalk-Environments-Part-1) em duas partes cobre esse cenário.
3. Usar Chef ou Puppet para distribuir a atualização para todas as máquinas que rodam o(s) serviço(s).
4. Criar uma AMI que já venha com um outro serviço responsável por atualizar o serviço principal, possivelmente monitorando algum bucket do S3, baixando a nova versão, parando o serviço principal, atualizando os arquivos e reiniciando o serviço. Basicamente reinventando Chef ou Puppet.
5. Escrever seus próprios scripts de AWS para criar uma AMI para cada atualização (há uma ferramenta chamada [Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro) que pode ajudar) e recriar/substituir a máquina EC2 a cada deployment. Isso é relativamente comum usando Linux, talvez com Windows seja mais demorado. Apesar de demorado esse pode ser a alternativa com menos downtime pois pode esperar até a nova versão estar totalmente pronta para trabalhar (ou já trabalhando) e só então desativar a antiga.

Answer (score 0):

O Elastic Beanstalk (não confunda com Elastic Load Balancer / ELB) possui um mecanismo de personalização, arquivos .config na pasta .ebextensions, nos quais você pode declarar comandos a serem executados e serviços a serem iniciados, entre outras opções. Veja mais detalhes na documentação do Elastic Beanstalk: [Customizing Software on Windows Servers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html).